# Oracle/Mysql editing large amount of records, recommendations?

Tags: java, php, mysql, oracle

First I want to thank you for all your help on the page, it's been really helpful. Now I've come across a situation that I cant figure out, and I hope you can help me, this is it:

At my workplace I have access to an Oracle DB with a table filled with users on it (names, lastname, birthdate and other stuff). It has 17 millions of records, and for each record I need to generate a unique key (lets say it's the 2 first letters of the name plus the birthdate concatenated, actually is more complex but it's an example), so for this key I need to retrieve the record, calculate the key and then update the record with the key. Now over 17 million records it's killing the server!!

So the DB at work is Oracle, I copied the data to my machine into a MYSQL database for testing. I was planning on testing locally making the calculations with php, and then create a java application to create the key on the server, but it's a massive workload!! I don't know which way to go. The simple select takes 10 minutes on php (on mysql via command line takes 1.49 minutes to COUNT() the records)

I know that it's better to calculate the key as the records come in. They arrive in packages of 500k but since I just got here, the data is already merged and I have to work on these records.

So what would you recommend this poor soul to do about such a task. I was thinking triggers or pl/sql but I'm really lost on what would be better in terms of performance.

Thank you very much!!!

-----------as a request from ogres and in hope you can help me, here's the code in php for the calculation I need to do for every row

```
$vn=0;//holds the value calculated for name
$sql="select * from roots";//table holding triplets for character|number (ex: 1|A|13), field names (consecutive|character|code)
$resultados=mysql_query($sql,$idcon);
while($dato=mysql_fetch_array($resultados))//i put all of the pairs in an associative array for quicker acces
{
    $consulta[$dato['v_propio']]=array($dato['caracter'],$dato['v_primo']);
}
//coding the name, for every char in the name i add to $vn, the consecutive times the position of the character in the string, plus the code for the character, if null, i add some values
$pos=1;
for ($i=0;$i<strlen($nombre);$i++)
{
    $char=substr($nombre,$i,1);
    $char=charnum($char);
    if($char!=NULL)
    {
    $vn=$vn+($char*$pos)+$consulta[$char][1];
    }
    else
    $vn=$vn + 28 + 107;
    $pos++;
}
//end of name coding
// i format the code for the name to 4 digits
if ( $vn < 1000 and $vn > 99 )
    $vn = '0'.$vn ;
else if ( $vn < 100 and $vn > 9 ) 
    $vn = '00'.$vn; 
else if ( $vn < 10 ) 
    $vn = '000'.$vn; 
 else
    $vn=$vn;
```

//FINALLY I CONCATENATE THE FIRST TWO CHARS IN NAME WITH THE CODE CALCULATED AND THE BIRTHDAY EX: JH235408071984 WOULD COME FROM FOR JHON BORN ON 1984/08/07 WITH NAME CODE CALCULATED= 2354

```
$CODE=trim(substr($nombre,0,2)).trim($vn).formatFecha($fnac);
```

HOPE IT HELPS AND YOU CAN GIVE ME SOME POINTERS!!

Comment: May not help, but in my experience (PHP + Oracle 10g2), to deal with large data, one possible way is to split into several relatively small chunks, e.g. to update 100 records, update id 1-10, then 11-20, and so on. And remember to do this at "idle" time (e.g. night), and prepared statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I generally do when faced with humongous data sets like this, is first set aside somewhere to keep track of where I am (just a single table can do the job), then run through the results 1000 or so at a time. Assuming you don't need the greatest degree of accuracy figuring out how many records are going to be (assuming there aren't huge gaping holes), and also to use the data for our looping, we can grab the approximate # of results with a query like:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS MinID, MAX(ID) AS MaxID FROM Users
```

Assuming you have a PK Identity named ID. This query should be pretty darned fast to do compared to a full COUNT(*) or COUNT(1). Then, you can test the table I mentioned above to see if the data exists, if not, start from the beginning, if so, start working on those IDs from wherever you left off. This probably needs to run for a really long time with that many records, but this can be done to make it able to rerun as necessary or just run forever until it is done.

It'll end up looking something like (lots of pseudo functions since I have no idea what platform or not you'll be using):

```
define("NUM_PER_ITERATION", 1000);

// Get our ID range
$query = "SELECT MIN(ID) AS MinID, MAX(ID) AS MaxID FROM Users";
$array = $MyDB->GetSingleRow($query);
$minid = (int) $array["MinID"];
$maxid = (int) $array["MaxID"];

// Get our last starting point
$startingpoint = LoadLastWorkPosition();
if (!$startingpoint || $startingpoint < $minid) {
  $startingpoint = $minid;
} else if ($startingpoint > $maxid) {
  echo("Already done!");
  exit;
}

// Run through the values
$curstart = $startingpoint;
while ($curstart <= $maxid) {
  $curend = $curstart + NUM_PER_ITERATION - 1;

  // Set a time out so it will keep running, you'll know way better
  // than I how long this should be for each loop
  set_time_limit(300);

  // Handle a number of results
  HandleResults($curstart, $curend);

  // Set the start of the next entry
  $curstart = $curend + 1;

  // Save our current progress
  SaveLastWorkPosition($curstart);
}

echo("All done!");
```

You'd have to design the LoadLastWorkPosition (which tries to load the last position and returns 0 or false or whatever if there isn't one), SaveLastWorkPosition (so you can keep track of where you left off... allows a separate script to check the value as well to see where it is for a progress bar or tracking) and HandleResults (load the IDs in a specific range and creates the unique values for them).

Anyways, hope that helps you get a start if nothing else!

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll try it and see how it goes, now, i have a doubt, how does the $MyDB->GetSingleRow($query); work? because my first reouble is when i do a select on the table, even if i use limit 1,10 (for example),it takes like a lot of time on the processing and fetching the results, any help on that?

Comment: GetSingleRow is just a sample of a function in a framework so I didn't have to specific mysqli, PDO, Oracle, or whatever interface you are using. I didn't want to put in every single part of the process to do the query, grab the result, modify if it there is none, etc. It would just grab a single row from a query.

If doing something as simple as LIMIT 1, 10 is taking a long time to process, is there a key on whatever field(s) you are querying by? It sounds like there isn't and the query has to crawl the entire table to find a result. eg, "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = 1" - Put a key on ID

Comment: alright, got the id field, im working on it seems to be good with ranges in like 10,000 records per loop is taking 57 seconds aprox. now testing with 100,000 records at a time (select * from table where id between 1 and 100,000)to see how it works, so in conclusion  its better to do a lot of small selects (like the 100,000 at a time) than to select all of them right? sorry if it sounds stupid, but im new at handling large amounts of data ....

Comment: It depends on what DB communication interface you're using. Some, like the mysql_* (and I think mysqli_* but not 100% sure) will do a query and grab all the results at once, which can quickly run you out of memory. In general, if you're grabbing more than a few MB of data at a time, you may need to break up your grabs into separate portions. This also tends to be easier on the DB as well, since it only has to deal with a smaller data set at a time, instead of millions at once.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll keep that in mind for future development, so now if you dont mind telling me, when i finally get this to the java/oracle environment, i would do the same (small chunks in the EJB) or is it better to do these calculations on the database via PL/SQL?

Comment: That depends on a number of factors. If you are coding this once, for a single RDBMS (which sounds like the case), then if you can code the whole thing to run in SQL, do it all in SQL. That is generally the fastest method. If portability to other RDBMS is essential, you generally can't rely on them having even remotely similar scripting support, so in that case you may need to generate the codes in PHP.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much, now for the final question, if you're kind enough to tell me, what material can recommend for me to study so i can do all the operations using just SQL?  because my knowledge so far tells me all i can do with sql is extracting and storing data (yes, i'm a noob),so i have no idea where to start to do these operations in pure SQL (cutting strings and concatenating them, add numbers and stuff). Thank you very much for all your help so far!!

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not the right person to ask since I code everything for cross platform usage. The SQL I use works in MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc...

Comment: Thank you very much for everything, you've been so kind, i can't thank you enough, i'll just go and study all the sql books i can find!! Thanks again, see you around

Answer (score 1):

you do not have to use php for calculation , first , add a column for unique_key to your table , then create index/unique constraint on this column , after that you can update whole table once with sql , generated_value is unique_key for a row , calculated within SQL not by php

```
update table set unique_key = generated_value
```

, after this if you want to find person , you will calculate its unique_key and then use query

```
select * from table where unique_key = generated_value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, now @ogres, hope you can help me further, i'll give more details, the key i need to generate is done by a series of calculations using the namen and birthadates and a series of numbers, i can calculate this directly from sql?

Comment: alright, i get it, what i dont know yet is how can i calculate the value using sql only, i would need to use the name,surname,birtdate and a table with prime numbers to perform a series of calculations, can it be done using only SQL?

Comment: give me example of calculation in php or in a language u use , i`ll try to help you